# Mount Olympics?

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence, sequence, sports

A friend sent me the following sequence of numbers with the above title. They said it took them, and their friend wiki, 37 summers to frame it.

> 83, 55, 45, 44, 37, 36, 48, 46, 46, __

Can you help me solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sequence is

> the most number of gold medals won by a country in the summer Olympic Games, from 1984 till this year.

So the next number is

> [39](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Summer_Olympics#Medal_summary)